# Defining Model in Django

Tags: django

So I attempting to teach myself Django for a course I am in, but am struggling with how to approach the problem (I have read through the official tutorials, but still am a little lost).

Essentially I have a database with user information and I want to design a view that queries this database and renders the resulting information. However, in the tutorials models were always used to generate databases (https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/).

My question is, if I am just given a database (specifically a sqlite database) do I need to design a model for that database, or can I query it directly from the view? And if so, how would I go about doing so as I cannot find anything in the documentation related to this problem.

Thanks and please let me know if my description of the problem is ambigious, I am new to Django and web dev in general, so am still learning the terminology.

Comment: Does the given database has tables and data in there already?

Comment: Yes - the tables and data are provided for us

Comment: The tutorial isn't clear on this because it's assumed Django will generate and manage your data and database schema for you. Read [this section in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first define a database connection to the existing database, which is a setting that [described here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases).

As it is mentioned in the comment section, the tutorial assumes that you build the model first, then populate the database schema in your actual database. If you work the other way round, you need to populate the models by existing database schema. Use this command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

It would create a models file for you by inspecting the existing database. You might/might not need to tweak the generated code depends on your need, but it's always good to look at it and learn.